# How can I sort on a column so that row height doesn't change in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I have this Microsoft Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

When I sort on column `B`,  it changes the row height:

[image]

[image]

How can I sort on a column so that row height doesn't change?

I use Microsoft Excel 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Ctrl-A to select all cells, Home tab -> Alignment group -> deselect "Wrap Text".

[image]